# Need to perform update method on writable Nested serializers in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=255)

class Client(models.Model):

    client_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='org',null=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product,related_name='product')
    client_name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=100)
....
```

**serializers.py**

```
class Clientpost_Serializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    billing_method = Billingmethod_Serializers()
    product = Product_Serializers(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        billing_method_data = validated_data.pop('billing_method')
        product_data = validated_data.pop('product')
        billing_method = Billing_Method.objects.create(**billing_method_data)
        validated_data['billing_method'] = billing_method
        client = Client.objects.create(**validated_data)
        product = [Product.objects.create(**product_data) for product_data in product_data]
        client.product.set(product)
        return client

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        billing_method_data = validated_data.pop('billing_method')
        billing_method = instance.billing_method

        # product_data = validated_data.pop('product')
        # product = instance.product

        instance.currency = validated_data.get('currency', instance.currency)
        instance.currency_type = validated_data.get('currency_type', instance.currency_type)
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.street_address = validated_data.get('street_address', instance.street_address)
        instance.city = validated_data.get('city', instance.city)
        instance.state = validated_data.get('state', instance.state)
        instance.country = validated_data.get('country', instance.country)
        instance.pincode = validated_data.get('pincode', instance.pincode)
        instance.industry = validated_data.get('industry', instance.industry)
        instance.company_size = validated_data.get('company_size', instance.company_size)
        instance.client_name = validated_data.get('client_name', instance.client_name)
        instance.contact_no = validated_data.get('contact_no', instance.contact_no)
        instance.mobile_no = validated_data.get('mobile_no', instance.mobile_no)
        instance.email_id = validated_data.get('email_id', instance.email_id)
        instance.client_logo = validated_data.get('client_logo', instance.client_logo)
        instance.client_code = validated_data.get('client_code', instance.client_code)
        instance.save()

        billing_method.billing_name = billing_method_data.get('billing_name', billing_method.billing_name)
        billing_method.description = billing_method_data.get('description', billing_method.description)
        billing_method.save()
        # product.product_name = product_data.get('product_name', product.product_name)
        # product.save()

        product_data = validated_data.pop('product', [])
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)

        for products_data in product_data:
            product = Product.objects.get(pk=products_data.get('product_id'))
            product.product_name = products_data.get('product_name', product.product_name)
            instance.product_data.add(product)
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

When I tried to perform PUT request in Client Endpoint the billing method value is getting updated but the product value is not getting updated. As the product field is a many to many field and that's why I have given many = True and can't able to perform update on the nested serializer.

Kindly help to resolve this issue, as I was stuck here for so long can't able to figure out the problem. The error throwing while performing PUT is

```
DoesNotExist at /api/onboarding/client/02de2d7e-2345-4727-bfa5-5ea5ffa22c63/
Product matching query does not exist.
Request Method: PUT
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/onboarding/client/02de2d7e-2345-4727-bfa5-5ea5ffa22c63/
Django Version: 3.2.12
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Product matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: C:\Users\gobs4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py, line 435, in get
Python Executable:  C:\Users\gobs4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.4
Python Path:    
['F:\\PM-Onboarding-Service\\Onboarding-Service\\microservices',
 'C:\\Users\\gobs4\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\gobs4\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\gobs4\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\gobs4\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
 'C:\\Users\\gobs4\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 18 May 2022 17:37:48 +0530
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\gobs4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = await sync_to_async(response_for_exception, thread_sensitive=False)(request, exc)
            return response
        return inner
    else:
        @wraps(get_response)
        def inner(request):
            try:
                response = get_response(request) …
            except Exception as exc:
                response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
            return response
        return inner
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
exc 
DoesNotExist('Product matching query does not exist.')
get_response    
<bound method BaseHandler._get_response of <django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object at 0x000001D99899B190>>
request 
<WSGIRequest: PUT '/api/onboarding/client/02de2d7e-2345-4727-bfa5-5ea5ffa22c63/'>
C:\Users\gobs4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
        if response is None:
            wrapped_callback = self.make_view_atomic(callback)
            # If it is an asynchronous view, run it in a subthread.
            if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(wrapped_callback):
                wrapped_callback = async_to_sync(wrapped_callback)
            try:
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
            except Exception as e:
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
                if response is None:
                    raise
        # Complain if the view returned None (a common error).
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
callback    
<function ClientDetail at 0x000001D99ACE7370>
callback_args   
()
callback_kwargs 
{'pk': UUID('02de2d7e-2345-4727-bfa5-5ea5ffa22c63')}
middleware_method   
<bound method CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view of <django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware object at 0x000001D99899B640>>
request 
<WSGIRequest: PUT '/api/onboarding/client/02de2d7e-2345-4727-bfa5-5ea5ffa22c63/'>
response    
None
self    
<django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object at 0x000001D99899B190>
wrapped_callback    
<function ClientDetail at 0x000001D99ACE7370>
C:\Users\gobs4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py, line 54, in wrapped_view
def csrf_exempt(view_func):
    """Mark a view function as being exempt from the CSRF view protection."""
    # view_func.csrf_exempt = True would also work, but decorators are nicer
    # if they don't have side effects, so return a new function.
    def wrapped_view(*args, **kwargs):
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs) …
    wrapped_view.csrf_exempt = True
    return wraps(view_func)(wrapped_view)
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
args    
(<WSGIRequest: PUT '/api/onboarding/client/02de2d7e-2345-4727-bfa5-5ea5ffa22c63/'>,)
kwargs  
{'pk': UUID('02de2d7e-2345-4727-bfa5-5ea5ffa22c63')}
view_func   
<function ClientDetail at 0x000001D99ACE72E0>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need a

> product.save()

```
for products_data in product_data:
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=products_data.get('product_id'))
    product.product_name = products_data.get('product_name', product.product_name)
    product.save()
    instance.product_data.add(product)
instance.save()
```